# I want to extract all the information from inside this datalayer. But I couldn't. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-re

I tried: `(re.findall(r'dataLayer = (.*?)]), I guess it;s a wrong syntax for this issue.But I want to grab info such as: "base_price_excl_tax". should only give me 99.99 value. but it didn't work!

```
<script>
// if the dataLayer variable isn't set, create it as an empty array
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({"base_price_excl_tax":99.99,"base_price_incl_tax":99.99,"ecomm_prodid":"XXXX","ecomm_totalvalue":99.99,"availability":"bbb","base_image":"nnn.jpg","pageType":"gup"});
```

Comment: Hi, could you check the syntax of your code please? I guess the closing quote is missing, I guess it is right before the bracket ), right?

Comment: Btw. `re.findall(r'dataLayer = (.*?)\]', string)` seems to work for me, it returns: `['dataLayer || [']` or isn't that, what you expect?

Comment: Well I want to grab for example: "base_price_incl_tax" this info